# Where is the nice Ubuntu download page?

Tags: downloads

I can't find the GOOD download page for Ubuntu. I keep getting bounced around dumb pages with very frustrating and mostly useless options.

This page (and anything that stems from it apparently) is bad for me (only offers bad options not good for my computer):
https://www.ubuntu.com/download.

Just once, I found a page with like 6 or 8 options (BIG ORANGE BUTONS FOR MONKEY TO PRESS) offering Ubuntu .iso files by direct download (AND TORENT MAGNET LINK BUTTON ONE ONE SIDE OF THE BIG ORANGE BUTTONS, but I can't use torrents). Some buttons were for 32 bit some were for 64 bit. They were organised on 2 rows and 3 or 4 columns. The ISO images offered were for 16.04 LTS. The options were like Ubuntu, Ubuntu mini , XDE ubuntu and micro something. Each option, again, had both 32 and 64 bit image.

Have you seen this page? Can you give me a link, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Scroll down to the bottom and select the mirror you would like (based on your country, i am using [US mirror](http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/)). It will lead you to a index of ubuntu releases. Choose the one you want. That will lead you to a choice based on your PC/laptop/machine.

Good Luck

Comment: Ok... Thx for trying at least.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Go to the above site and you can find 2 download buttons, one for  16.04[lts] version and the other for 17.04 version. Click on the one you want, then if you want to donate something then great, you can do it in that page but if you don't then you can just slide the slider to zero for all options and then download it for free.

Hope it helped.